# Dynamically hide/show a div based on table scroll position using Javascript/jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table with a sticky header, and I want to dynamically hide/show a div with the class "price" based on the table scroll position. When I scroll and the scroll reaches the table header, it stays at the top, and the table scrolls. However, I want to hide the div with the class "price" when the table starts scrolling and show it again when it reaches the top. I mean at start of the scroll some details in the table header should disappear and it will stay like that. If I scroll back and I reach the top again, it should appear. How can I achieve this?

Here's my HTML structure and JavaScript code:

```js
$('.plan-price-container').on('scroll', function() {
  console.log("HERE");
  // Add your logic to hide/show the div with class "price" based on the scroll position
});
```

```css
.plan-price-container .matrix-container {
  display: block;
}

.plan-price-container table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.plan-price-container thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.plan-price-container th,
.plan-price-container td {
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: left;
}

.plan-price-container th {
  background-color: #B7FFBF;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 120%;
  letter-spacing: -0.56px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height:600px">
  djfjfkj
</div>

<div class="plan-price-container">
  <div class="feature-container">
    <div class="matrix-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div class="plan-header">
                <div class="plan-header-title">
                  <h3>Heading 1</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                  <div class="price">
                    <h4 class="payment">Monthly Prices</h4>
                    <h4 class="payment-annual">Annual Price</h4>
                  </div>
                  <a href="link" class="black-button">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div class="plan-header">
                <div class="plan-header-title">
                  <h3>Heading 2</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                  <div class="price">
                    <h4 class="payment">Monthly Prices</h4>
                    <h4 class="payment-annual">Annual Price</h4>
                  </div>
                  <a href="link" class="black-button">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div class="plan-header">
                <div class="plan-header-title">
                  <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                  <div class="price">
                    <h4 class="payment">Monthly Prices</h4>
                    <h4 class="payment-annual">Annual Price</h4>
                  </div>
                  <a href="link" class="black-button">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height:300px">
  djfjfkj
</div>
<div style="height:300px">
  djfjfkj
</div>
<div style="height:300px">
  djfjfkj
</div>
<div style="height:300px">
  djfjfkj
</div>
```

Currently, when I add the following CSS:

```css
.plan-price-container {
    height:600px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

The scroll event is triggered only for the `.plan-price-container`. However, this causes an internal scroll for the table, and I need to specifically scroll within the container for the table header to stick to the top and scroll the table contents. How can I modify this code to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example of your problem!

Comment: That is the question itself.

Comment: Your first paragraph is not really very clear. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And there appears to be no sticky behavior in the current version of this snippet either.